# Returning just a section of a url parameter

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I've got this javascript function which returns a url parameter for me called 'name':

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
      return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
    }
```

It works well, if my parameter is this: name=David%20James then it returns David James, but I just want it to return the first name 'David' for example. I'm not sure how to do this. I need to tell it to just return the first name, so everything up to %20.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
=([^%]*)
```

The first (only) matched group is the desired portion, "David", in this case.

- `=` matches `=` literally
- Then the captured group `([^%]*)` gets the portion upto next `%`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vL2lP7/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use .split(" ") function as well

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    String[] x = name.split(" ");
    String firstname = x[0];
          return firstname ;
          }
```